# Flask: matplotlib's. pyplot.save_fig() gives file_not_found error for new path

Tags: python, matplotlib, flask

I'm not sure if this is an issue with flask or an issue with matplotlib. I've been able to access images in html and javascript, but now I can't seem to do it in python.

I have a directory tree structure like the following

```
\---Neuroethics_Behavioral_Task # 'root' directory for my flask app. Contents are shown below

+---jspsych-6.0
|   +---css
|   ## cutting this directory off here, jspsych is just a framework I'm using, not relevant
+---static
|   +---images
|   +---plugins
|   |   \---template
|   +---textdata
|   \---trial_stimuli
+---templates
\---__pycache__
```

I've just been using a script called `experiment.py` that lives in the topmost directory of my flask app (so in the /Neuroethics_Behavioral_Task/ folder). It executes a function called "generate_stim_for_trials(trials)". Create_stimuli uses matplotlib to create a bunch of pngs, each representing stimuli, and it's supposed to save these images in the /static/images/ directory.

I'm omitting most of the code related to the stimulus creation for... "ownership/copyright" purposes. Also that code really shouldn't be relevant All that needs to be said is that I create a pandas dataframe and plot it in matplotlib.

```
def generate_stim_for_trials(trials):
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import json
import os
lst_of_jsons_for_stimuli = []
stim_metadata_path = "/static/textdata/stimulus_data.json"
for each in range(trials):
    stimuli_in_static = "images/stimulus_img" + str(each) + ".png"
    stimuli_path = url_for('static', filename=stimuli_in_static)
    # started ommitting code here...
    df = # df variable gets created
    df.plot(kind='barh', legend = False, stacked=True, color=['#e26a6a', '#3CB371', '#A9A9A9'])
    plt.axis('off')
    plt.margins(x=0)
    plt.margins(y=0)
    plt.grid(b=None)
    plt.savefig(stimuli_path, bbox_inches='tight', pad_inches=-1) # error
```

The error I get is ultimately: `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/static/images/stimulus_img0.png'`. I have the full error message but it's pretty long (and if moderators don't think it's useful, feel free to remove it/tell me to remove it).

```
     Traceback (most recent call last):


File "D:\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2463, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "D:\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2449, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "D:\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1866, in handle_exce
ption
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "D:\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "D:\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2446, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "D:\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1951, in full_dispat
ch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "D:\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1820, in handle_user
_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "D:\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "D:\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1949, in full_dispat
ch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "D:\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1935, in dispatch_re
quest
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "D:\Projects\CogNeW\Neuroethics_Behavioral_Task\experiment.py", line 21,
in exp_js_psych_app
    generate_stim_for_trials(total_trials)
  File "D:\Projects\CogNeW\Neuroethics_Behavioral_Task\experiment.py", line 93,
in generate_stim_for_trials
    plt.savefig(stimuli_path, bbox_inches='tight', pad_inches=-1)
  File "D:\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 722, in save
fig
    res = fig.savefig(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\figure.py", line 2180, in sav
efig
    self.canvas.print_figure(fname, **kwargs)
  File "D:\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_qt5agg.py",
line 88, in print_figure
    super().print_figure(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backend_bases.py", line 2082,
 in print_figure
    **kwargs)
  File "D:\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_agg.py", lin
e 530, in print_png
    cbook.open_file_cm(filename_or_obj, "wb") as fh:
  File "D:\miniconda3\lib\contextlib.py", line 81, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
  File "D:\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\cbook\__init__.py", line 447,
 in open_file_cm
    fh, opened = to_filehandle(path_or_file, mode, True, encoding)
  File "D:\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\cbook\__init__.py", line 432,
 in to_filehandle
    fh = open(fname, flag, encoding=encoding)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/static/images/stimulus
_img0.png'
```

Again, this python file `experiment.py` exists at the topmost level of the flask module, in the "neuroethics_behavioral_task" directory. So it should be able to understand the path, `/static/images` since the static folder is also at that same level. But it doesn't.

Furthermore, here I'm trying to create/save a new file called `stimulus_img0.png.` So indeed, this file shouldn't exist yet -- it's getting created.

I can't tell if this is a matplotlib or flask issue, and I"m not sure how to resolve it because I'm not sure where my python program is actually looking at this point.

**Edit 1**

Well the 'mystery' is solved.

You know how you're supposed to do `flask run` or `python -m flask run` from a directory above your flask app?

If I just make the line `plt.savefig('stimuli_img0.png')`, the image(s) get saved in the directory above my flask application, aka the directory from which I'm executing `python -m flask run`.

So now my question is... What actually controls where python scripts in Flask save to? Is this actually the default behavior? I haven't encountered this in the html or js files in this flask app.

Comment: Do you have the subdirectory `images` inside `/static/`?

Comment: Yes. That's what the directory tree structure is supposed to verify.

Comment: Oh, but you are working in windows, so which drive does `static` live on? You should probably do, e.g. `D:/static/images/stimulus_img0.jpg`

Comment: I mean I can try that it's just that the intention was to actually deploy this application online someday so an absolute file path (if that's the correct term) wasn't what I was going for. 

Also here's some further info: I have a function in experiment.py called example_stim() that does the same thing as this function, it just generates only 1 image rather than looping for trials. If I run that function by itself (`python experiment.py`), that program can save successfully to the `static/images` directory and make a new file. Trying to run the program in Flask on another hand...

Comment: @QuangHoang `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'D:/static/images/stimulus_img0.png'`

Comment: @QuangHoang see the edit.

My question is now: Is that actually supposed to be the default behavior of a python script in flask?