# How to serve, reference, and save static files in Flask/python app.py or views.py files, avoiding FileNotFound errors

Tags: python, nginx, heroku, flask, static

Similar to this question, but there's some follow ups I have. [How to serve static files in Flask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20646822/how-to-serve-static-files-in-flask)

The main issue I'm having in adapting the solution from that previous post is that I need to use matplotlib's `.savefig()` function, which just takes in a string for a path to save to. So I need to know what string to pass it.

I remember having a lot of issues with static files when I was first working on my Flask application locally. I don't know how I'm supposed to correctly reference the path of static files from my `app.py`/`views.py` python file. I understand using `url_for()` in html and what not, but referencing the static files in python hasn't been as straightforward.

My flask app has the following structure. The root directory is called `Neuroethics_Behavioral_Task`

[image]

I have a file called `experiment.py` and that file is basically a `views.py` or `app.py` file. But I can't seem to find the correct way to reference static files.

Here's the `experiment.py` code.

```
import functools

from flask import (
    Blueprint, flash, g, redirect, render_template, request, session, url_for, Flask
)
from werkzeug.security import check_password_hash, generate_password_hash


app = Flask(__name__, instance_relative_config=True, static_url_path='') # creates the flask instance

bp= Blueprint('experiment', __name__)


@app.route('/')
@app.route('/index')
def index():
    return render_template("welcome.html")

@app.route('/experiment_app', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def exp_js_psych_app():
    total_trials = int(request.form['trials'])
    import random 
    import string 
    user_id = ''.join([random.choice(string.ascii_letters 
                + string.digits) for n in range(8)]) 
    user_id = str(user_id)
    stim_metadata = generate_stim_for_trials(total_trials, user_id)
    return render_template("index.html", data={"user_id": str(user_id), "total_trials":total_trials, "lst_of_stim_jsons":stim_metadata})
def generate_stim_for_trials(trials, uid):
    import matplotlib
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
    import json
    import os
    json_dict = {}
    json_dict["stimuli path info"] = []
    lst_of_jsons_for_stimuli = []
    # Unused but problematic static reference.
    stim_metadata_path = "/static/textdata/stimulus_data" + str(uid) + ".json"
    # Another problematic static reference.
    stimuli_path = '/static/images/stimulus_img' + 1 + ".png"
    df = pd.DataFrame({"Risk":[25], "No Effect" : [50], "Gain":[25]}) 
    df.plot(kind='barh', legend = False, stacked=True, color=['#ed713a', '#808080', '#4169e1'])
    plt.axis('off')
    plt.gca().set_axis_off()
    plt.subplots_adjust(top = 1, bottom = 0, right = 1, left = 0, hspace = 0, wspace = 0)
    plt.ylim(None,None)
    plt.autoscale()
    plt.margins(0,0)

    plt.savefig(stimuli_path) # this fails
```

Something to note is that passing in the `static_url_path` parameter to the `Flask()` call isn't really working as intended, I thought that this would establish the root as the place to first look for my static files but the fact that this code is still failing suggests otherwise, since my `/static/` directory is clearly in the root folder.

Otherwise as I said... I need to use `plt.savefig()` which takes in a path, and I still can't figure out how I'm supposed to write this path.

I have managed to get static files to be working prior to this point. I had to change the two references above to static files to the following:

```
stimuli_path = 'Neuroethics_Behavioral_Task/static/images/stimulus_img' + "1" + ".png"
stim_metadata_path = "Neuroethics_Behavioral_Task/static/textdata/stimulus_data" + str(uid) + ".json"
```

In other words, I could get static files before by including the root directory in the path.

and this at least got me by... Until I tried to deploy my app onto Heroku. Then I started to get errors that `Neuroethics_Behavioral_Task/static/images/` wasn't a recognized path... so now I feel like I need to actually start referencing static files correctly, and I'm not sure how to at this point.

I've tried variations (ex: `images/stimulusimg1.png`) and tried changing the `static_url_path` parameter (ex: `static_url_path='/static/`), but these have all just caused my Flask application to crash locally saying FileNotFound.

Another important follow up question I have...

This application is going to be on an online experiment posted on Amazon Mechanical Turk. Images are supposed to be preloaded by a framework I'm using called JsPsych. But posts like this and the one I first included encourage you to serve files using NGINX [What exactly does 'serving static files' mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28918845/what-exactly-does-serving-static-files-mean)

I have no idea how Nginx or wsgi work. Should I still bother to try to get all of my static files served this way, and if so how do I start?

So in summary the questions I'm asking are

- I need to save static files in my `experiment.py`/`views.py`/`apps.py` file, and so I need to figure out the string that actually denotes the path to my static images. How do I do that? Do I actually need to modify the `static_url_path` variable?
- Why have I previously been successful with referencing the root directory in my paths to static files
- My images are supposed to be preloaded by a javascript framework I'm using, JsPsych. Should I still go through the trouble of setting up nginx and wsgi configuration?

edit: `url_for()` isn't working either.

```
stimuli_in_static = "images/stimulus_img" + "1" + ".png"
stimuli_path = url_for('static', filename=stimuli_in_static)
```

This still results in a FileNotFound error at the `.savefig()` call,

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/static/images/stimulus_img1.png'
```

Comment: For static files your should always use the url_for function. You are importing it already in your code. Just doing `url_for('static', filename='images/stimulus.png')` shoud do the job just fine.

Comment: @MrLeeh See my edit... that isn't quite workingg surprisingly. I had tried it a while ago. It's still getting a FileNotFound error.

Comment: Than there is something wrong with your configuration. What url are you getting?

Comment: @MrLeeh I'll edit it into the question, but the `stimuli_path` variable comes out as `/static/images/stimulus_img1.png`. Also what do you mean by "something is wrong with my configuration?" Also note that the `url_for` calls are succcessful in Jinja/html.

Comment: @MrLeeh I found this old question from me (which went unanswered). The last comment I made is important - if I just do a `plt.savefig("stimulus_img")` then that by default gets saved into the root directory. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57877056/flask-matplotlibs-pyplot-save-fig-gives-file-not-found-error-for-new-path

Comment: I found something in the Flask tutorial that I never got to. I actually never made a setup.py file for this project. I'm not sure if it can help me at this point but... https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/tutorial/install/

Comment: Ah now I see. You are trying to save the image. Sorry, I missed that. For saving a file you don't want a URL but a normal file path. It should be enough to omit the slash at the beginning: `static/images/stimulus.png`. Make sure the directory images exists.

Comment: This is doomed to fail, because Heroku's filesystem storage [is not persistent](https://help.heroku.com/K1PPS2WM/why-are-my-file-uploads-missing-deleted). Every time the app restarts (which could be anytime) saved data will be deleted. The recommended workaround is to use the AWS S3 object store, which Heroku has [native support for](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3-upload-python).

Comment: Additionally see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31485660/python-uploading-a-plot-from-memory-to-s3-using-matplotlib-and-boto) on how to get `plt.fig` to write to a BytesIO buffer (instead of a file) then upload it to S3.

Comment: @V25 can a dyno shut down for a user is using the application? The `savefig()` call is something that happens once the user gets past the homepage of my application, then jspsych is launched which preloads these images and uses them for the duration of the experiment. Unless a dyno shuts down between someone going on my homepage... I'm more concerned about the fact that I needed to save the experiment data as csvs, which I did intend to keep in the static directory and now I know that won't be possible. Either way, I'll use S3 for both of these issues to be safe.

Comment: Call me a little annoyed because I feel like Flask and Heroku have so much critical information that they just don't really highlight in their tutorials nor keep it in a very centralized place...

Answer (score 1):

As per my comments, because Heroku doesn't support persistent filesystem storage, the recommended method is to use S3.  To do that you'll need to have `plot.fig` write to a Bytes IO buffer, then upload that to S3.  This process is covered in [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31485660/python-uploading-a-plot-from-memory-to-s3-using-matplotlib-and-boto).

Either way, here's an answer on the static file stuff regardless, which is permissable on Heroku provided the static files in question are actually part of the repo (javascript and CSS files, etc)...

---

`static_url_path` is designed to change the URL which static files are available at.  That affects the **frontend URL** path from which static files are available.

With the following config static files are available at `http://example.com/apple/` regardless of where they are on the filesystem:

```
app = Flask(__name__, static_url_path='apple')
```

If you want to define where Flask looks on the **filesystem** for static files, use `static_folder` instead.  In your case the application is at `app_dir/experiment.py` and your `static` directory is at the top level.  So you need to provide that argument relative to where `experiment.py` is:

```
app = Flask(__name__, static_folder='../static')
```

Personally I try to do away with this whole headache and create a directory structure which conforms to what Flask expects by default:

```
project
├── experiment.py
├── static
│   └── some.js
└── templates
    └── some.html
```

---

One other tip regarding your code:

```
def generate_stim_for_trials(trials, uid):
    import matplotlib
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
    import json
    import os
```

This is inefficient, because all of these imports will be loaded each time that function is called.

You really want to put those imports at the top of the file, so they load when the app server runs, and only then.:

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import json
import os

# ...

def generate_stim_for_trials(trials, uid):
    json_dict = {}
    # ...
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I just wanted to ask you... Consider the flask documentation, they offer a 'simple module' organization pattern (the first file structure they discuss) then a more complicated 'package' organization pattern (the second file structure they discuss). In this answer, you were outlining what Flask expects by default for the 'simple module' structure, correct? https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/tutorial/layout/ . Also in my original question, `app_dir` is actually empty and `/static/` and `template` are 1 level within my project dir `Neuroethics_Behavioral_Task`.

Comment: In my original question, I was trying to go for the "single module" organization pattern - I was trying to do what you suggested. `experiment.py` and `__init__.py` were all just 1 level inside of my project dir, `Neuroethics_Behavioral_Task`. Again, `app_dir` was empty. And this was still causing me problems, or it didn't seem to avoid the "headache" you're talking about. I'm about to post my answer/solution, the way I actually finally got this working on heroku was by using the second organizational pattern discussed in Flask's docs, the `package` organization pattern.

Comment: @ByronSmith yes, I seem to have misread your directory strucutre, and assumed `app_dir` contained `experiment.py`.  As a side note, you may actually get away with using filesystem storage for your use-case, I guess you can test it and see. This has been a long day lol, probably not my finest answer.

Comment: I am a little concerned though. The images sound like they might be safe even with Heroku's "ephemeral" file storage. But I don't think the csvs that are generated at the end of every experiment are safe if the things on heroku's FS truly do get wiped out every time a dyno restarts and if a dyno always restarts on a daily basis.  I wanted to just accumulate those csvs then come back to them for analysis after I had like maybe 200 of them from 200 subjects. So I think S3 is still needed. And nah this answer was really helpful, thank you a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Consider flask's documentation on how to organize flask applications. The first file structure they talk about is the 'simple module' pattern, the second file structure is the more complicated 'package' pattern.  https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/tutorial/layout/

I was originally trying to impelement a "simple module" pattern. The contents of `app_dir` were empty. Instead, `Neuroethics_Behavioral_Task` was my project directory, and 1 level inside of it were my `experiment.py`, `__init__.py`, `/static/` and `/templates/` folders.

I was able to get past these FileNotFound errors by switching to the package-based organization pattern for my flask app. So the file structure now looks like

[image]

In this scheme, `Neuroethics_Behavioral_Task` is still the project directory. But now there's `app_dir` which contains `__init.py__`, `experiment.py`, `/static/` and `/template/` all in the same directory.

When I made this change, I was able to rewrite most of the save() statements in `experiment.py` to something like this.

```
# inside of generate_stim_for_trials()
csv_path = "app_dir/static/textdata/" + subj_id + "_data.csv"
```

In other words, all I had to do was use the app_dir prefix.

This worked both on my local machine and it worked once I pushed the code to heroku. I'm still using this "package" based organization pattern since it's what flask at least recommends for complex applications.

On another hand, V25 made a very crucial point that Heroku does not provide permanent storage, which may totally change your plans if you're deploying your stuff to heroku like I am. I'm glad I mentioned that I intended to do that.